# R output without [1], how to nicely format?

Tags: r, formatting, output

I know stuff has been posted, but not as complete as what I am looking for.

Take any help function (i.e. `?mean`), and realise that it's output (or at least output should be able to be generated in the same manner).

How do you get enters, alignment/intendation?

Example:

```
strings <- c("t", "df", "p-value", "mean of x", "mean of y")
values  <- c(t, df, pvalue, mean1, mean2)
```

If this would be the things you'd want to output in R (when called from a function), how do you make the `[1]` disappear, and the values lined up?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is rather elementary, please consult [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html) as well as

- `help(cat)`
- `help(sprintf)`
- `help(format)`

and many more.  See the (literally thousands) of examples in formatting functions. Here is a simple example from one of my packages:

```
print.summary.fastLm <- function(x, ...) {
    cat("\nCall:\n")
    print(x$call)
    cat("\nResiduals:\n")
    print(x$residSum)
    cat("\n")

    printCoefmat(x$coefficients, P.values=TRUE, has.Pvalue=TRUE)
    digits <- max(3, getOption("digits") - 3)
    cat("\nResidual standard error: ", formatC(x$sigma, digits=digits), " on ",
        formatC(x$df), " degrees of freedom\n", sep="")
    cat("Multiple R-squared: ", formatC(x$r.squared, digits=digits),
        ",\tAdjusted R-squared: ",formatC(x$adj.r.squared, digits=digits),
        "\n", sep="")
    invisible(x)
}
```