# Compute one sample t-test for each column of a data frame and summarize results in a table

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

Here is some sample data on my problem:

```
mydf <- data.frame(A = rnorm(20, 1, 5),
                   B = rnorm(20, 2, 5),
                   C = rnorm(20, 3, 5),
                   D = rnorm(20, 4, 5),
                   E = rnorm(20, 5, 5))
```

Now I'd like to run a one-sample t-test on each column of the data.frame, to prove if it differs significantly from zero, like `t.test(mydf$A)`, and then store the mean of each column, the t-value and the p-value in a new data.frame. So the result should look something like this:

```
      A    B    C    D    E
mean  x    x    x    x    x
t     x    x    x    x    x
p     x    x    x    x    x
```

I could definitely think of some tedious ways to do this, like looping through `mydf`, calculating the parameters, and then looping through the new data.frame and insert the values.
But with packages like `plyr` at hand, shouldn't there be a more concise and elegant way to do this?

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109652/r-output-without-1-how-to-nicely-format) also might help you if you are using `regress`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this and then extract the results you want from the resulting table:

```
results <- lapply(mydf, t.test)
resultsmatrix <- do.call(cbind, results)
resultsmatrix[c("statistic","estimate","p.value"),]
```

Gives you:

```
          A         B          C            D           E           
statistic 1.401338  2.762266   5.406704     3.409422    5.024222    
estimate  1.677863  2.936304   5.418812     4.231458    5.577681    
p.value   0.1772363 0.01240057 3.231568e-05 0.002941106 7.531614e-05
```

Answer (score 1):

a `data.table`  solution :

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(mydf)
DT[,lapply(.SD,function(x){
         y <- t.test(x)
         list(p = round(y$p.value,2),
              h = round(y$conf.int,2),
              mm = round(y$estimate,2))})]

           A          B         C         D         E
1:        0.2       0.42      0.01         0         0
2: -0.91,3.98 -1.15,2.62 1.19,6.15 2.82,6.33 2.68,6.46
3:       1.54       0.74      3.67      4.57      4.57
```

Comment: Might be nice to have row names. Also, I tried to format your code, but it just requires a carriage return to format correctly, so I didn't hit the 6 character minimum edit.

Comment: @Thomas thanks. I was away. But there isn't rownames with data.table.

Comment: Is there a conceptual advantage of `data.table` that justifies the additional code, compared to the solution from @Thomas ?